# Loop through all fields of a Grails Objects of unknown properties

Tags: loops, grails, groovy, grails-orm

I currently have an ask to provide a "Lookup Table Management" interface to super users of an app I'm working on. They want to make changes to lookup tables that are used throughout the app (they won't be able to change IDs, of course).

I'd like to come up with a way to generically handle this without having to create a form for each LUT. Or if there is a plugin I don't know about that would be even better

All the LUTS are vastly different from each other in terms of fields. I'm trying to write a loop to loop through all the fields of a LUT object and then spit out the values for each object of that LUT.

Example:

**DrinksLut**

```
String name
Double price
Integer numSold
```

**PetsLut**

```
String name
Integer age
String breed
String size
Boolean fixed
```

I'm trying to provide a table output that lists the field properties as headers as well as the individual object values for rows depending on the LUT they choose to edit (Pets, Drinks, etc.)

**Current Code**

```
def resultList() {
    def selectedLut = grailsApplication.getClassForName(params.lutFilter?.replace('class ', ''))
    
    /* get field names, types and a "user friendly" name to use in the table header */
    def objProps = new DefaultGrailsDomainClass(selectedLut)?.persistentProperties.collect {
        [
            name: it.name,
            type: it.type,
            friendlyName: Helper.splitCamelCase(it.name)
            
        ]
    }
    
    /* get all rows for the chosen LUT */
    def results = selectedLut.getAll()
    
    render(template: '../lookupTable/resultList', model:[results: results, objProps: objProps])
}
```

...

```
<table id="lutTable" class="col-xs-12">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <g:each in="${objProps}">
            <th>${it.friendlyName}</th>
        </g:each>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <g:each in="${results}">
        <tr>
            <td>${it}</td> <!-- this currently is the object of a LUT and I need to get each of its field properties and values to spit out here -->
        </tr>
    </g:each>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I'd greatly appreciate any assistance or ideas! The app s using Grails 2.5.5

Comment: `"not IDs and whatnot"` - What is included in the "whatnot" that needs to be accounted for?

Comment: Sorry, that was misleading. I meant they won't be able to change IDs of existing LUTs (because that could create a nightmare) but they can change the other properties

Comment: Have you considered using scaffolded controllers/views for this?

Comment: @Daniel
I'm not sure what that is but it looks like for 2.5.5 I'll need to look at the scaffolding plugin.  So far (unless I am missing something or misunderstanding) it doesn't look like it is what I need. Correct me if I'm wrong but isn't this meant to help generate new classes? All mine are existing, I just have to manipulate the data in a generic way

Comment: I think taking a look at the scaffolding plugin may be helpful to you.  It is not for generating new classes, but instead for automatically generating controllers and views to work with existing domain objects.  I don't remember grails 2.5.5 version, but I think you can even use the plugin to generate the code and then modify it as needed.